# How to make debug work for phonegap-android application?

Tags: android, html, debugging, cordova

I have an android application which i am developing in eclipse using phonegap. Right now i am using alerts to check the data but I need debugger to debug the html and jquery javascript pages as it is taking very long time to check the data. I tried to implement my code in android studio but still there is no debugger which supports html pages. Can anyone please help me with how to debug html in eclipse or android studio?

Comment: You want to debug on the device or in a navigator on your desktop ? By the way, you should use console.log(..) (appears in logcat) instead of alert(...)

Comment: @gaepi yah i am using console also but whatever it is we need to write an extra lines of code to see the output but i want something like visual studio debugger which will show instantly

Comment: I've never been able to debug on the device (I didn't search so much). I ran the application on chrome and I used its debugger. Sure you are not able to test phonegap functions, but you can check everything else  (like in VS)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this once: [Ripple Emulator](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org) - it enables debugging on Chrome browser.

In order to debug, just go to the app's directory and run it: `cordova build && cordova serve`

and then connect the web-browser to it, e.g.

`http://localhost:8000/android/www/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.2.0`

Meanwhile the ripple emu is available on [GitHub](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-ripple.git) - just be sure to checkout the docs, how to build the Chrome extension. Alternatively, it's  be available on the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en). Just not really sure if it works for Cordova 3 yet, still trying.

Answer (score -1):

Some news.

I recently discovered this site which allow you to debug phonegap application on your device.
[debug phonegap](http://debug.phonegap.com/)

For the rest you can launch your application on Chrome by using a Wamp server for example or by starting Chrome like this :

```
cd C:\...\Google\Chrome\Application
start chrome.exe C:\...\yourpage.html --disable-web-security
```

In Chrome you can run the debugger by pressing F12. You have a console like in Visual Studio, you can add breakpoints, and check data like you want, and some other powerful functionnalities.

In your code you can add a condition around all phonegap functions to check if you are on your device or your desktop :

```
function isRunningOnDesktop()
{
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") < 0 &&
       navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") < 0 &&
       navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And to finish 2 links which may help you :
[link1](https://gist.github.com/purplecabbage/476358), [link2](http://www.thegalaxytabforum.com/index.php?/topic/621-detecting-android-tablets-with-javascript/)