# How can I inspect a phonegap application on android?

Tags: android, cordova, xdebug

I've been strugglin for a while now trying to debug a phonegap app.

I am using the npm tool for compiling and building phonegap apps, which is the standard way now (when you go on the phonegap website, they make you use this or phonegap build).

Now, with this way, I can't see console messages. I can still use eclipse for android to see the logs, but it is dumb that they give you a tool for building apps which doesn't deliver debugging functions.

Anyway I can't debug with only console.log messages, I am trying to find a way of using an inspector for that. Can't I use chrome's remote debugger on android ? I've tried weinre, their docs are poor and there is a total absence of tutorials online. Should I use adobe's edge inspector ? Or is it only for mobile browsers ?

I am starting to ask myself if I shouldn't switch to another cross platform technology. Even the official adobe's doc on debugging doesn't help at all.

Comment: answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297928/how-to-make-debug-work-for-phonegap-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want this debugger fo javascript with phonegap:
https://www.jshybugger.com/#/

Comment: seems nice althought not free. But the doc is poor and doesn't explain well how it works. I installed the phonegap plugin successfully but it doesn't show up anything. Tried to connect to my phone IP:8888 from my desktop browser but it doesn't work.

Comment: check this if you want to inspect the dom elements or css:http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: as stated in subject, I have already tried weinre and couldn't get it to work

Comment: Are you sure that you assigned the correct bounding host param to wienre server? because I'm already using it

Comment: i have jshybugger working. I needed phonegap 3.x and their phonegap plugin that's all. The problem is that license isn't free. Gonna give it a try and see if it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Titanium Mobile, which is another cross-platform mobile development kit. It uses javascript and compiler to create **native** applications. As far as i know, it have a good debugging tool, which is more easier to use than PhoneGap or Sencha Touch.

Comment: I am giving it a try right now. A shame because apart from debugging, Phonegap is a really great solution. But debugging is essential for developing of course so..

Comment: I forgot to say that Titanium supports PhoneGap too, so I think you can use debugging tool in your hybrid application (hybrid application uses PhoneGap).

Comment: I thought titanium compiled to native components ?

Comment: You can build both native and hybrid (PhoneGap) applications with it. As far as i know this SDK uses some kind of Web Mobile build to create PhoneGap based apps.

Comment: Didn't know about html/js based generation from titanium. Gonna take a look into it